# Had usage problem

Tags: past-perfect

1)India won the toss and decided to bowl.

why not

2)India **had** won the toss and decided to bowl.

As the event of winning the toss occurred first.

Comment: Hello, mannu. The events described by 'won the toss' and 'decided to bowl' are very close together in time, and in an obvious order to someone understanding the way these things are done (ie almost everyone). Using 'and' is a marker of sequentiality here; 'did X and Y' often means 'did X and then, almost at once, Y'. The past perfect is often used sparingly (or even avoided) when confusion about meaning doesn't arise.  In fact, after 'India had won the toss and decided to bowl' you'd expect something like 'and now they were reaping the benefits' (ie A, A'; and then, some time later, B)....

Comment: (No partisanship intended; I just hope it's a good match tonight. I live near Manchester, and it might just rain.... And the Aussies look like they're the form team)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with *"India had won the toss and decided to bowl."* It's just that the *"had"* is unnecessary (the order of events is perfectly clear without it), and most of the time we don't put it in.